# Central Typedefs.h file - is it a good idea?

Tags: c++, typedef, header-files

Coming from the Java world, in which there are no typedefs, I have a question for C++ developers:

My task is to rewrite a large MATLAB project in C++. In order to get to know the structure of the code, I have started rebuilding the module and class structure without actually implementing the functionality.

I know that I frequently need classes/types like `Vector` and `ParameterList`, which will be provided by some framework I have not decided on yet.

So I created a central header file `Typedefs.h` in which I have type definitions like

```
typedef void Vector; // TODO: set vector class
typedef void ParameterList; // TODO: set parameter list class
```

For now, these are set to void, but I can use these types to write class skeletons and method signatures. Later I can replace them with the actual types.

Is this something that makes sense? If yes, is there a way to avoid manually including the `Typedefs.h` in every file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt this would work, unless you use, for example `Vector*`. You wouldn't be able to have `Vector` objects or parameters, so it's pretty much pointless.

And for use as a pointer, you can very well do a forward declaration.

Anyway, I don't really see the need for any of this. You can declare an empty class without having to implement it, and it's even easier to write than a `typedef`:

```
 typedef void Vector;
```

vs

```
 struct Vector{};
```

Comment: I see that I cannot use variables and parameters of type void, only pointers. Instead of void, I could set the typedefs to some dummy class. However, simply using empty structs might be the better solution I didn't think of.

Comment: Empty structs - empty of data but not of meaning.

Comment: Forward declared structs or classes can be also passed by value in a function declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Note that you will not be able to overload functions with `typedef`s that map to the same type:

```
void foo(Vector);
void foo(ParameterList);   // error: foo(void) already declared
```

Comment: I think this is a minor issue, since `void foo(Vector x);` wouldn't compile even by itself...